# Error in web worker using importScripts(defiant.min.js)

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I'm trying to use defiant.js in a web worker, since I'm doing heavy computation in addition to the JSON.search.
However I keep getting a

> Uncaught Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Defiant is not defined

I created a simple example using part of the defiant demo code.

Does anyone know whether this is a defiant.js issue or am I just importing the script wrong?
Or is there another solution on how this can be done?

JS in main.html

```
var obj = {
    "car": [
        {"id": 10, "color": "silver", "name": "Volvo"},
        {"id": 11, "color": "red",    "name": "Saab"},
        {"id": 12, "color": "red",    "name": "Peugeot"},
        {"id": 13, "color": "yellow", "name": "Porsche"}
    ],
    "bike": [
        {"id": 20, "color": "black", "name": "Cannondale"},
        {"id": 21, "color": "red",   "name": "Shimano"}
    ]
}
    var worker = new Worker('defiantWW.js');


    worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
      console.log( e.data);
    }, false);
    worker.postMessage(obj);
```

web worker file

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    importScripts('defiant.min.js')
    var obj=e.data;
    var search = JSON.search(obj, '//car[color="yellow"]/name');
  self.postMessage(search);
}, false);
```

EDIT
changing the position of importScripts() as suggested by dandavis in comments - but same result

web worker file v2

```
importScripts('defiant.min.js')
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    var obj=e.data;
    var search = JSON.search(obj, '//car[color="yellow"]/name');
  self.postMessage(search);
}, false);
```

Comment: you should import up-front at load, not upon each message, which could screw things up

Comment: Thank you - changed the position of the importScripts() and edited the question, but result stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly enough defiantJS does not support the use within a web-worker.
Got [feedback from Hakan Bilgin](https://github.com/hbi99/defiant.js/issues/83) on the issue:

> There is already support for web workers in Defiant.js

```
<script src="defiant.min.js"></script>
<script>

var obj = {
    "car": [
        {"id": 10, "color": "silver", "name": "Volvo"},
        {"id": 11, "color": "red",    "name": "Saab"},
        {"id": 12, "color": "red",    "name": "Peugeot"},
        {"id": 13, "color": "yellow", "name": "Porsche"}
    ],
    "bike": [
        {"id": 20, "color": "black", "name": "Cannondale"},
        {"id": 21, "color": "red",   "name": "Shimano"}
    ]
};

Defiant.getSnapshot(obj, function(snapshot) {
    var found = JSON.search(snapshot, '//car');
    console.log(found);
});

</script>
```

> [Snapshot] doesn't give me access to defiant from within my own web-worker.
>   I can execute the Snapshot in the main thread and then post the result to my web-worker, however the large JSON (5-15mb) is handled only in the web-worker. I would have to pass it over to the main thread, run the Snapshot (which is executed in another web-worker) and then pass the result back to my WW.
>   Since I'm using the JSON.search quite often that would induce a lot of unnecessary overhead on the main thread.
>
> No...you can not access Defiant from within a web worker

Answer (score 0):

hi to load a service worker try this link:

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers

as it mentioned:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(function(registration) {
      // Registration was successful
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
    }, function(err) {
      // registration failed :(
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
    });
  });
}
```